# Does internet activity of all my browsers remain hidden from ISPs?

Tags: security, socks

After getting connected to Tor, when other internet browsers are configured on socks 127.0.0.1:9150 will their internet activity remain hidden from Internet Service providers and Trackers?

Comment: Hi there, could you please try to summarize this question a bit in the title? Generally a title should explain the question in a few words without details. I've tried to rephrase the question part, but wasn't entirely sure what you were asking. Fore some useful hints see "[How do I ask a good question?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" in the help center. Thanks!

Comment: In the question it is not clear what was providing the socks service before connection of the Tor client. I suppose the Tor client will provide socks on the port 9150. --- What do you mean by "Trackers"?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Tor acts as a filter in a way, encrypting and pumping into the tor network any communications sent through its proxy port of `127.0.0.1:9150`. Any browser using this port correctly will have its connection torified, and [check.torproject.org](https://check.torproject.org/) will show a green onion if the browser is configured correctly.

*Warning:* Tor will only torify connections sent to its proxy port. It will not proxify connections from applets or plugins using settings differing from your browser. Always consider connections made from a plugin not known to use proxy settings correctly as **unsecured and traceable**.

Answer (score 3):

If I use Tor browser bundle for windows, other browsers are not automatically torified, so, to torify other browsers, you will have to use ADVTor: http://sourceforge.net/projects/advtor/

there is an option to run specific application through ADVtor software.

Maybe it is different in linux, but as far as I know, here are some explanations: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO#Howtotorifyspecificprograms